# Flexbox - take the element right "flex-direction: column" without use position in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

`Flexbox` - take element right `flex-direction: column;` without use `position` in CSS
Hey guys I want to take my element (one row) to right, but without use positioning.

This cod contain `flex-direction: column;` and I can't control rows position.
How can I achieve it in right way with `flexbox` elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(247, 176, 232);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: margin-left:auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flex-direction` got nothing to do with positioning what it do is just to change the direction of an element in 4 ways that are `row`, `column`, `column-reverse` and `row-reverse` so use [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) on the `div.box` instead where you will set it to `flex-end` to align it the `right` or `flex-start` to align it to the `left`

> Note: `self-align` depends on the `flex-direction` means that values on `flex-direction` can affect it

### Example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(247, 176, 232);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `margin-left` property sets the left margin of an element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(247, 176, 232);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
.right-element {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box right-element"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```